# Closed form for $1/(n (n + 1))$

Tags: summation, closed-form

What would the closed form be for 
$$
g(n) = \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + ... +  \frac{1}{n \cdot (n+1)}\;\;?
$$

An example would be $g(3) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12} = 0.75$

Comment: See [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the idea of a telescoping sum.

$\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}=\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}$.

Now sum it up from $k=1$ to $n$, and you shall see certain cancellations happening.

Comment: @Auser They are. Use common denominators to show this.

Comment: @voldemort is the sum 1?

Comment: @Auser: No- the sum is $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the idea of partial fractions to split the fraction apart:

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{A}{k} + \frac{B}{k+1}$$

Now we find $A$ and $B$:

$$1 = A(k+1) + Bk$$

When $k = -1$:

$$1 = -B, B = -1$$

When $k = 0$

$$1 = A$$

Therefore, our fraction now becomes:

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$$

This helps because now we can cancel out the terms, which I'm sure you can see now.

Comment if you have questions.

**EDIT**

If you expand the summation to $n$ terms, we can see that:

$$\left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + ... + \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

So the terms cancel out, and we get that:

$$S(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Taking the limit as $n$ approached infinity:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S(n) = 1$$

Therefore the sum converges to $1$/

Comment: would the sum be 1? I've evaluated it for n=1 to n=4 and they start all canceling except 1

Comment: Yes! As you go to n, you'll notice that all the terms get canceled except $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $1$. So taking the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, we see that the sum converges to $1$.

Comment: don't they all cancel except the term 1/n?

Comment: look at my updated answer

Comment: thank you for helping me through this. 1 more question though: where does the second to last term, (1/(n+1)−1/n), come from?

Comment: messed that up I'll fix it sorry

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get where that 2nd to last term is coming from?

Comment: We said that we are evaluating the terms for $n$ amount of terms. Therefore, the last term is substituted for $k=n$. Also, if you are content please feel free to upvote/check to tell other users that the answer is accepted and correct.

Comment: yes but what about the second to last term in the sequence, (1/(n−1)−1/n)? Where is this coming from?